# BigQUery repeating date array for a list of values

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

In Bigquery,I am trying to generate a table for a list of partners that would have a repeated array showing the year / quarter. Ideally this would be an ongoing sheet which would allow me to update and add additional quarters as time goes on.

```
Partner          Year    Quarter
---------        -----   --------
Partner 1        2021    Q1
                 2021    Q2
partner 2        2021    Q1
                 2021    Q2
```

So far I have tried using "Generate date array" to give the first day in the quarter and then add that to give the Quarter and the year. However all I get is the

```
With dates as (SELECT
Generate_date_array('2021-01-01', '2021-04-01',INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)as YQ)
Select
["Partner 1","Partner 2"] as partners,
YQ
FROM dates
```

However this only gives me two rows

```
Partner          Date 
---------        ----------
Partner 1        2021-01-01
partner 2        2021-04-01
```

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
with dates as (
  select extract(year from date) year,
    'Q' || extract(quarter from date) quarter 
  from unnest(generate_date_array('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31',interval 1 quarter)) as date
), partners as (
 select partner from unnest(["Partner 1","Partner 2"]) as partner
) 
select partner,
  array_agg(struct(year, quarter)) calendar
from partners, dates
group by partner
```

with output

[image]